# How to draw stick trefoil knot

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, parametric, knot-theory, knot-invariants

[image]

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stick_number_trefoil.png
 I am interested in plotting the stick trefoil knot. I don't know where to start. I am looking for equations or co-ordinates of vertices, so that i can plot it. 
Thanks

Comment: +1 It looks a little like an optical illusion. Do you want to plot the 2d projection of it?

Comment: I wish to plot it in 3d...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first distribute same labels:

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

Let the $C$ lie at $(1,0)$,  $F$ at $a(1,0)$, $A$ at $(\cos(2\pi/3),-\sin(2\pi/3))$ and $D$ at $a(\cos(2\pi/3),-\sin(2\pi/3))$. You need to check whether $|CD|=|AF|$ and this is:
$$
|(1-a\cos(2\pi/3),-a\sin(2\pi/3))|=|(a-\cos(2\pi/3),-\sin(2\pi/3))|\\
\sqrt{(1-a\cos(2\pi/3))^2+a^2\sin^2(2\pi/3)}=\sqrt{(a-\cos(2\pi/3))^2+\sin(2\pi/3)}\\
1-2a\cos(2\pi/3) +1 = a^2+2a\cos(2\pi/3)+1\\
a^2+2a-1=0\\
a=\sqrt{2}-1
$$

ok I skipped ambiguities with the squares and the roots of the last equation...
For your information, these graphs are called [Unit distance graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph).

Comment: It is the minimal version of Trefoil Knot (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot).

Comment: It is the minimal version of Trefoil Knot . I want plot it in 3d. For trefoil knot parametric equations are available (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot). But i want to have a equations that defines stick trefoil knot, shown in link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick_number.   Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Don't the "sticks" always bend a little, like this [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Ehz.jpg)?

Comment: Dear draks... sticks bend a little if we have to project the trefoil in plane. But in 3d it need not so. I wish to experiment by plotting the answer given by you. Now i am having something to start with....  Thanks.

Comment: @kumar you're welcome (to Math.SE!)...